# How do you make a long string of characters make a line break to start a second line in a td tag?

Tags: html-table, css-tables, line-breaks

A long string of characters contained in a td tag and that string will continue on one line and won't make a line break and I have to scroll towards the right to see the y's on the right side.

**How do I make it so that the line containing x will make a line break after filling up 50% of the window so I can see all the x's and y's without scrolling?**

```
 <html>
<style>
    .table
        {
            border-width:   1px;
            border-style:   solid;
            border-color:   black;
            text-align:     center;
            width:          100%;
            overflow-wrap:  break-word;
            word-wrap:      break-word;
        }
</style>
<body>
    <table border= '1'class = 'table'>
        <tr>
            <td class = 'left'>Left</td>
            <td class = 'right'>Right</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
            </td>
            <td>
                yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the CSS property:

```
word-wrap: break-word;
```

You can add it as a style attribute inside your TD tag, or create a CSS rule for TD in your stylesheet.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is add `word-break: break-all;` to your `<td>` tags.